# Toggle visibility of a selected object illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, cs6

I have found that toggle visibility off of a selected object is command+3 on mac from what I searched up but for some reason it doesn't toggle the object back on?

Comment: So that you can continue hiding objects. Once an object is hidden (or locked, which works the same way), the only way to undo that is to show every single hidden object. There's no selecting a hidden object and then unhiding selected objects... So it's divided into 2 different shortcuts. If it was a toggle, you wouldn't be able to hide more objects later without first having to show every single hidden object, then selecting the old hidden objects + the new object you want to hide. — You can find lock and hide in the top menu under "Object > Hide" and you can see the shortcut there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using CC not CS6

command+3 hides selection

alt/option+command+3 toggles the hidden object(s) back on